# dual feasibility of Kuhn-Tucker condition?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

minimize $f(x)$

subject to 
\begin{align}
f_i(x) & \le 0, \quad i \in \left\{ 1,\ldots,m \right\} \\
h_i(x) & = 0, \quad i \in \left\{ 1,\ldots,p \right\}
\end{align}

Then the Lagrange function is given by
$$L(x,\lambda ,v) = f(x) + \sum \lambda _i f_i(x) + \sum v_i h_i(x)$$
and
$$g\left( {\lambda ,v} \right) = \inf L\left( {x,\lambda ,v} \right)$$ where $g$ is the lagrange dual function,

and for any $v$ and any $\lambda\ge0$ then we have $g(\lambda ,v) \le {p^*}$

---

This was what I found from the wikipedia for the nonlinear optimization technique. Everything was understandable except the last line saying that $\lambda\ge0$.

so my question is that why we have to set lambda to be non-negative for inequality constraint while the sign of lagrangian multiplier does not matter for equality constraints

Comment: One answer is that you can't prove that $g(\lambda,\nu) \leq p^\star$ without the assumption that $\lambda \geq 0$.  Just go through the proof and you'll see this assumption is needed.

Comment: Yes. Without that sign condition, you would be treating the inequality constraints exactly the same as the equality constraints. Surely that has a consequence.